# wrap $ in span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to wrap any dollar signs `$` in a span so that I can style them accordingly, without having to go back through and editing each `$` I find on the page. The code I've tried to use was for ampersands, and works perfect for ampersands, but I can't get it to work correctly with a dollar sign!

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried using just  the `$` symbol, and `&#36;`, but neither are giving me the results needed. Instead it doesn't touch the `$` that is wrapped in the `<p>`, but instead adds it right before the closing `</p>`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tk8og3Ln/

HTML:

```
<p>Cabana Tanning Lotion: $32.00</p>
```

jQuery:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.money = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var element = $(this);
      var html = element.html();
      element.html(html.replace(/$/gi, '<span class="money">$</span>'));
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('p').money();
```

CSS:

```
.money {
  font: italic 1.3em Baskerville, Georgia, serif;
  color: #666;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: did you try escaping the $:   /\$/gi

Comment: ha! perfect! that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of the answer from @guest271314, I also needed to make sure to wrap the code in a document.ready function to allow WordPress to initialize the jQuery. 
Here is the finished code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.money = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var element = $(this);
      var html = element.html();
      element.html(html.replace(/\$/gi, '<span class="money">$</span>'));
    });
  };

$('p').money();

});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$` is `RegExp` symbol for end of line. You can use `"$"` or escape `$` `/\$/`.

Comment: sorry to be a bother again, although it is working on JSFiddle, I cannot get it to work on my wordpress site. Do you mind taking a look?

Comment: Is `jQuery` defined?

Comment: yes, jQuery is defined. I modified the code so that i don't get the console error $ is not a function, but it still does not work.

`(function($) {
  jQuery.fn.money = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var element = $(this);
      var html = element.html();
      element.html(html.replace(/\$/gi, '<span class="money">$</span>'));
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery('p').money();`

Comment: here is the site and page that i need all $ to change: https://bronzeluxury.wpengine.com/our-products/

Comment: See [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries)

Comment: @Trisha Debugging your entire website is beyond the scope of Question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136905/discussion-between-trisha-and-guest271314).